# Route users to different paths according to information entered in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My userinfos controller handles user information. As soon as the user signs up, I want them to go to the page that lets them fill out the user information like name, email, gpa, college...Lets just say they leave before completing the form, when they sign in again, I want to check if the user information has been filled out, if not, I want to take them to enter the new information page. To do this, I added the "info_complete" function to my userinfo model(as shown below).
Here are my two models which will tell you the relationship between them.

Userinfo model:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :videos, through: :user

    def info_complete?
        name? && email? && college? && gpa? && major?
    end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :userinfos
  has_many :videos

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Then I added the following code to the application controller.
My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.userinfo.info_complete?
      redirect_to root_path
    else 
      redirect_to new_user_info_path
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to log in after saving this, I get the following error:[image]

Full error trace:

```
activemodel (4.2.3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `after_sign_in_path_for'
devise (4.3.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:21:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the full trace? I can't see where the error lies given what information you have supplied.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added it now

Comment: Can you post the `create` method of `sessions_controller`?

Comment: Hmm... I still don't really understand the error message (is that definitely the most up-to-date version of the code??), but there are two clear issues: 1) If the user `has_many :userinfos`, then `user.userinfo` (singular) is not defined. Should that be `has_one`? Or if not, then should the redirect logic be either `resource.userinfos.all?(&:info_complete?)` or `resource.userinfos.any?(&:info_complete?)`? And 2) the `after_sign_in_path_for` is supposed to just specify the **path** and not actually perform a redirect.

Comment: See the documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for

Comment: @TomLord It worked! I tried changing it to "has_one", then it gave me "undefined info_complete method" error. Then I changed it back to has_many and changed the logic the way you suggested. It worked after that. Do  you want to add this as an answer so I can choose yours as the right one? I'm new to this site, but if I choose your answer as the correct one, you get points or something, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it appears the relationship between `user` and `userinfo` is a bit muddled up.

If the user can really **`have_many :userinfos`**, then why are you only trying to check one of them? (`resource.userinfo.info_complete?`) That's not valid syntax, since `resource.userinfo` (singular) isn't even defined; you'd need to either write this as:

```
resource.userinfos.all?(&:info_complete?)
# or
resource.userinfos.any?(&:info_complete?)
```

Or alternatively (probably the right answer?), you should change the model relationship to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :userinfo
```

---

A second issue is that the [`after_sign_in_path_for` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for) is supposed to only *return a path*, and not actually perform the redirect. So, that method should look something more like:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.userinfo.info_complete?
      root_path
    else 
      new_user_info_path
    end
  end
```